# Bootstrap theme doesn't work on mobile device (but work on computer, even when resize browser to min width)

Tags: theming, javascript

While on mobile device:

- Main Menu (the default one): On top I see the site name with beside the "toggle navigation" button (which don't respond) and above a vertical list of
  menu items. And the menu has no more border, background-color, etc...
- Views carousel: I see a vertical list of images id ("1.", "2.", "3.", etc...) and above a vertical list of my images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried from another mobile (mine is nexus 4) and the problem doesn't appear.

Finally, I installed the module bootstrap_library and the problem disappeared.